# Set a constant boundary query

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am using Sqoop to import MySQL tables to HDFS. To do that, I use a free-form query import.

```
--query "SELECT $query_select FROM $table where \$CONDITIONS"
```

This query is quite slow because of the min(id) and the max(id) search. To improve performances, I've decided to use --boundary-query and specify manually lower-bound and upper-bound.
( https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/apache-sqoop-cookbook/9781449364618/ch04.html):

```
--boundary-query "select 176862848, 172862848"
```

However, sqoop doesn't care about specified value and again tries to find minimum and maximum "id" by itself.

```
16/06/13 14:24:44 INFO tool.ImportTool: Lower bound value: 170581647
16/06/13 14:24:44 INFO tool.ImportTool: Upper bound value: 172909234
```

The complete sqoop command:

```
sqoop-import -fs hdfs://xxxxxxxxx/ -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=" -Duser.timezone=Europe/Paris" -m $nodes_number\
    --connect jdbc:mysql://$server:$port/$database --username $username --password $password\
    --target-dir $destination_dir --boundary-query "select 176862848, 172862848"\
    --incremental append --check-column $id_column_name --last-value $last_value\
    --split-by $id_column_name --query "SELECT $query_select FROM $table where \$CONDITIONS"\
    --fields-terminated-by , --escaped-by \\ --enclosed-by '\"'
```

Does anyone has already met/solved this problem? Thanks

Comment: Do not answer your own question as an edit but put it as an answer. You can then accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct..

We should not use **--split-by** with **--boundary-query** control argument.

Comment: what is the reason behind not using --split-by with --boundary-query control argument

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this problem by deleting the following arguments:

```
--incremental append --check-column $id_column_name --last-value $last_value
```

It seems that there is a concurrency between arguments --boundary-query, --check-column, --split-by and --incremental append

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
--boundary-query "select 176862848, 172862848 from tablename limit 1" \
```

Comment: This query leads to the same result as mine.

However, I managed to solve my problem by deleting

` --incremental append --check-column $id_column_name --last-value $last_value `

It seems that there is a concurrency between these arguments, the --split-by argument and the --boundary-query argument.